# Zebra-printer LP 2824 not printing

Tags: zebra-printers

I have Zebra LP2824 printer. It is working properly on Windows XP, but It is not working properly on Windows 7. On windows 7 it prints the Test page on printer properties, but it is not printing in my application. It seems, that it can't find the port, the printer is using. On the same application, but on Windows XP it is printing. I am connecting the printer with USB.
Does anyone knows what seems to be the problem?
Thanks for help in advance. :)

Comment: Are there any drivers installed in either system?

Comment: @OviTisler Yes, on both systems are drivers. If there wont be any drivers, then I could not print out the Test Page, I think

Answer (score 0):

I usually have to share the printer in order to get it to accept a print job. Sharing in Win 7 is a little different I think - there might more than one step. Open the printer queue and pause it, then send a print job to it - see if it shows up (then un-pause) If it doesn't show up in the queue, there might be a share/permissions problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just managed it today to print on another zebra USB printer.

use this article : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322091/nl

Notice dough that the sample has a small error, so go to this function

```
    public static bool SendFileToPrinter( string szPrinterName, string szFileName )
    ...
    ..
```

overthere go to then end of that function and add the line i mention below

```
    Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pBytes);
    fs.close(); // <-- add that or it will crash with locked files errors.
    return true;
```

How Zebra printers behave depends a lot on what you try to print, and how the program works
For example notepad and edlin and wordpad and dos PRINT can all work different.
Some programs print RAW directly (as the url code does), others pay some respect to the printer preferences > still dough a TXT file raw printed containing ZPL commands will overrule printer settings..

ZPL is a little nightmare in itself
If you need paper to be cut
You will need
^MMC

you wont find it explained like that in their manuals. 
(because they sell their own label printing design software i think..)

Comment: I'll have a look at that article, hope this will help.